# Where are the packages in init react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The `npm init react-app my-app` command imports many packages to the project, but, why this dependencies are not in the `package.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies are in the `package.json` of `react-scripts` which your project will depend on when initializing it. The only dependency of your project will be `react-scripts`.

If you want to manage these yourself you need to [eject](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) your project.

Comment: But the command generates just two dependencie: `react` and `react-dom`. But my node_modules has many packages differents. Where are they settings?

Comment: @FabianoLothor They are depenencies of `react-scripts`. Dependencies can have dependencies themself which can again have dependencies themself.... All these will be installed but in your project you will only have the first class dependencies listed. Browse to `react-scripts/package.json` in your node_modules and you will see them there.

Comment: Oh! `react-script` has all dependecies!? Now I can understand this. Thanks!